# BERT transformer not working for my NLP task - error message not understood

Tags: python, nlp

I am attempting to uses a BERT model to perform sentence classification on my own
selection of English texts, pre-processed and labelled and in a Pandas data frame. I am a PhD
researcher but my computing knowledge is not too much beyond basic Python 3, hence my
struggles, as some of the subtlety of what is actually going on will be lost on me. I have never
posted on such a forum before so I apologise for any transgressions on the following!
Here is the COLAB cell which is generating the issues…

```
BERT_MODEL_HUB = model
from fast_bert.learner_cls import BertLearner
from fast_bert.metrics import accuracy
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
device_cuda = torch.device("cuda")
metrics = [{'name': 'accuracy', 'function': accuracy}]
learner = BertLearner.from_pretrained_model(
 databunch,
 pretrained_path=BERT_MODEL_HUB,
 metrics=metrics,
 device=device_cuda,
 logger=logger,
 output_dir='/content/sample_data',
 finetuned_wgts_path=None,
 warmup_steps=500,
 multi_gpu=True,
 is_fp16=True,
 multi_label=False,
 logging_steps=50)
```

Here is the BERT model I am trying to use…

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
```

I am using FastBert…

```
from fast_bert.data_cls import BertDataBunch
data_path = '/content/sample_data' # needs to be a directory?
label_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/LABEL_DIR'
train_file = '/content/Dickens_Carroll_train.csv'
valid_file = '/content/Dickens_Carroll_valid.csv'
databunch = BertDataBunch(data_path, label_path,
 tokenizer=tokenizer,
train_file=train_file,
val_file=valid_file,
label_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/l
abels.csv',
 text_col='text',
 label_col='Source_Label',
batch_size_per_gpu=16,
max_seq_length=512,
multi_gpu=True,
multi_label=False,
model_type='bert')
```

Here is the error message I receive…

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call
last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distpackages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls,
pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
 241 if resolved_config_file is None:
--> 242 raise EnvironmentError
 243 config_dict =
cls._dict_from_json_file(resolved_config_file)
OSError:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
OSError Traceback (most recent call
last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distpackages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls,
pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
 249 f"- or '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' is
the correct path to a directory containing a {CONFIG_NAME} file\n\n"
 250 )
--> 251 raise EnvironmentError(msg)
 252
 253 except json.JSONDecodeError:
OSError: Can't load config for
'<transformers.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertModel object at
0x7f04b8310668>'. Make sure that:
- '<transformers.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertModel object at
0x7f04b8310668>' is a correct model identifier listed on
'https://huggingface.co/models'
- or '<transformers.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertModel object at
0x7f04b8310668>' is the correct path to a directory containing a
config.json file
```

I shall be grateful for advice, explanation and direction please – thanks in advance! Mark
P.S. I have tried this, to no avail..

```
!pip install -q pyopenssl
```